# electron-forge: get cli arguments when running app like: npm run start --name=test

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-forge

package.json:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
```

`electron-forge version: electron-forge@5.2.4`

i want to run electron app and pass arguments to the cmd, so that i can use them in the app, e.g.:
`npm run start --name=test`
so i could use `name` inside the app

i tried all variations of that command:
`npm run start -- --name=test`
`npm run start name=test`
but nothing worked

when i `console.log(process.argv)` i get:
`[ 'C:\\app\\node_modules\\electron\\dist\\electron.exe', '.' ]`

how can i get the arguments passed?